# subsetting rows from a file by matching columns from another file

Tags: awk

I have tab separated files, files file 1 and file 2.  I would like to create a file 3 subsetting rows consisting of all the four columns from file1, matching both column 1 and 2 from file 2, The **file1** looks like:

```
1 17626 A G 
1 20184 G A
1 108826 C G
1 108929 G C
```

And, **file2** as:

```
1 17626 
1 20184
```

I would like the output as below in file 3

```
1 17626 A G
1 20184 G A
```

I have tried the following codes looking at the previous questions:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2]'  file2   file1 > file3

awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0'  file2   file1 > file3

awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]; next} FNR==1 || $1$2 in a' file2   file1 > file3
```

From the above two commands, I get an empty file. And, using the last command, I get just one line output instead of the expected two lines.

Comment: At least your last trial works fine, considering you handle header with `FNR==1`, `$1$2 in a` is unparenthezised, `$1$2` should be `($1,$2)` and you don't consider `\r` line endings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in arr)' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

In case its tab delimited then try following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2];next} (($1,$2) in arr)' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  arr[$1,$2]                  ##Creating array arr with index of $1 and $2 here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(($1,$2) in arr)              ##Checking if $1,$2 is present in arr then print line.
' Input_file2  Input_file1    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: @AVA, In my humble opinion, I would request you to open a new question for this, you could add complete  details along with your efforts(in code form) and we could discuss it there. Editing base Q & A will confuse users, cheers. Let me know once you open a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have opened a new question now.